# Trying to create a While Loop in PYthon to find strings in other strings

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to implement this function. It seems simple enough but my code is failing and I don't know why.

```py
def findall(text,sub):
    """
    Returns the tuple of all positions of substring sub in text.
    
    If sub does not appears anywhere in text, this function returns the empty tuple ().
    
    Examples:
        findall('how now brown cow','ow') returns (1, 5, 10, 15)
        findall('how now brown cow','cat') returns ()
        findall('jeeepeeer','ee') returns (1,2,5,6)
    
    Parameter text: The text to search
    Precondition: text is a string
    
    Parameter sub: The substring to search for
    Precondition: sub is a nonempty string
    """
    import introcs
    result= ()
    pos=0

    while pos < len(text):
        x=text[pos:pos+2]
        if x is sub:
            result=result+(x, )
            pos+1
        else:
            result=result
            pos+1
    
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in the current code. The following is minimally corrected one, with some suggestions (in the comment).

```py
def findall(text,sub):
    result= ()
    pos=0

    while pos < len(text):
        x=text[pos:pos+len(sub)]  # use len(sub) instead of 2
        if x == sub:              # use == instead of is
            result=result+(pos, ) # store pos, not x
            pos = pos+1           # assign RHS to pos
        else:
            result=result
            pos = pos+1           # assign RHS to pos

    return result

print(findall('how now brown cow','ow')) # (1, 5, 10, 15)
print(findall('how now brown cow','cat')) # ()
print(findall('jeeepeeer','ee')) # (1, 2, 5, 6)
```

In particular, `is` checks whether two objects are the same entity. To compare the strings by their contents, `==` should be used in general.

Using generator expression instead:

```py
def findall(text,sub):
    return tuple(i for i in range(len(text)) if text[i:i+len(sub)] == sub)
```